# TabLayout shows a blank fragment, the second time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

In my Android application I'm using a `TabLayout` with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to show dynamically generated fragments.
It shows correctly the fragments the first time, but when going back to some that are already viewed and are not the adjacent ones it shows a blank page...

I've looked into this and there seems to be two way of fixing this:

- Using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, which I already did and it didn't change anything.
- Change
  `adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(*getSupportFragmentManager*());`
  into:
  `adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(*getChildFragmentManager*());`
  that I can't do because I'm in `AppCompatActivity` and this method is in Fragment...

Is there a way to solve this issue without extending this activity out of `FragmentActivity` that would screw up other stuff in my project?

Code:

```
private class SubsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

    SubsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentsList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentsList.add(fragment);
        titleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
subsPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.subsPager);
                        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_view);

subsPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(subsPager)
```

Edit - Fragment Code:

```
public class PostsListFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<CustomPost> posts;

private Sorting sorting;

private String name;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private SubPostsAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private Fetcher fetcher

public PostsListFragment() {
    this.posts = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static Fragment newInstance(String name) {
    PostsListFragment pf = new PostsListFragment();
    pf.name = name;

    return pf;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_list_holder, container, false);

    //default sorting
    this.sorting = Sorting.HOT;
    this.fetcher = new Fetcher(name);

    loadItems();

    return recyclerView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

private void loadItems() {
    if (posts.size() == 0) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                posts.addAll(fetcher.fetchPosts(sorting));

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext());

                        adapter = new SubPostsAdapter(posts, getActivity());

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "shows a blank page"? 1) are you recreating a Fragment at any point? 2) can you show the code of an example Fragment that this happens to?  A ViewPager stills calls the full life cycle of a Fragment, so if it's blank and going to download data, it'll do it again later

Comment: The fragment is only a recyclerview that displays text/images downloaded from a url based on a name string.

Comment: Your problem is `pf.name = name` is set as null when you swipe back to the Fragment. That's not how to set instance variables to Fragments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because I just went in debug and the variable has the name in it, but the fragment is still blank

Comment: Secondly, I'm not sure what `fetcher.fetchPosts` does, but it looks like a blocking network call, and Android doesn't really like those. If you look at Volley or Okhttp for HTTP calls, you'll notice how they use callback methods to return results. Ideally, a low level `Thread` shouldnt need to be used

Comment: Just try `setArguments` since that's the correct pattern.  Then, feel free to implement onResume method of the Fragment to call loadItems() again

Comment: Then, that inner Thread is pointless. All the methods there for the recyclerview can go in onCreateView. You can set an adapter and layout manager with an empty list. You just need to call notify dataset change method of the adapter in the first thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was more stupid then it looked, removing this line:

```
 if (posts.size() == 0) {
```

from loadItems in the Fragment, makes it work as intended. 
Thanks to [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) for the advices!